# MVC3 Dropdownlist null in post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, foreign-keys, html-select

I have been working on this for several days and haven't got anywhere.  My Movies model keeps failing in my post, and it's because my dropdownlist value is null for parentGenre.  I checked firebug and the correct value is being posted.  Here is what I have so far:

Movies Model:

```
  public class Movies
{
    public Movies()
    {
        this.inventory = new HashSet<Inventory>();
        this.transactions = new HashSet<Transactions>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int movieID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Director is required")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public String Director { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An actor is required")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public String Stars { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    [AllowHtml]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre is required")]
    public virtual Genres parentGenre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Duration is required")]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Rating is required")]
    public String Rating { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Release date is required")]
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Inventory> inventory { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Transactions> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Genres Model:

```
public class Genres
{
    public Genres()
    {
        this.movies = new HashSet<Movies>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int genreId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A genre name is required")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public String genreName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Movies> movies { get; set; }
}
```

Movies Controller:

```
public ActionResult addMovie(int? page)
    {

        ViewBag.Ratings = new SelectList(new[] { "G", "PG", "PG-13", "R", "NR" });



        ViewBag.parentGenre = new SelectList(movieRepository.Genres, "genreId", "genreName");
        return View();


    }

    #region "POST"
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addMovie(Movies model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            movieRepository.AddMovie(model);
            movieRepository.save(model);
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

        ViewBag.parentGenre = new SelectList(movieRepository.Genres, "genreId", "genreName");
        ViewBag.Ratings = new SelectList(new[] { "G", "PG", "PG-13", "R", "NR" });


        return View(model);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("parentGenre", String.Empty)
```

Just to summarize, it hits the if statement to check if the model is valid, and fails because the "parentGenres" is null, even though the value is being posted in firebug.

Edit: Entire View:
    @model MovieRental.Models.Movies

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Movie was not entered in system. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-film"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { placeholder = "Title" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-facetime-video"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Director, new { placeholder = "Director" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Director)
        </div>

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-tags"></i></span>
            @Html.DropDownList("parentGenre", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.parentGenre)
        </div>  


        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stars, new { placeholder = "Actor" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Stars)
        </div>



        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration, new { @class="maskedDuration", placeholder = "Duration (mins)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
        </div>

        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rating, (SelectList)ViewBag.Ratings)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Rating)
        </div>



        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.releaseDate, new { @class="maskedDate", placeholder = "Release Date (mm/dd/yyyy)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.releaseDate)
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-comment"></i></span>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { placeholder = "Description", @class="input-xxlarge" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
}
```

Comment: addMovie creates a select list but does not send a model to your view. Are you model binding at all? please add your entire view.

Comment: are you model binding? i don't see one in your view?

Comment: I thought because the name was the same it would bind?  I can't do @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, String.empty) because it throws an error.

Comment: it often will. but I'm lost how you're using lambda's w/o giving something to bind against.

Comment: Oh my bad, the top didn't copy in.  I have @model MovieRental.Models.Movies.  I'll edit mine above.

Comment: That explains it. You're doing nothing clearly wrong, but I've found many more problems with loosely bound helpers. I find the tightly bound ones more reliable. check my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this to a dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, 
                     (SelectList) ViewBag.parentGenre, String.Empty)
```

except, I would strongly Recommend changing the name of your selectlist to parentGenreList as well

```
    ViewBag.parentGenreList = new SelectList(movieRepository.Genres, 
                               "genreId", "genreName");
```

so your resulting helper call would be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.parentGenre, 
                     (SelectList) ViewBag.parentGenreList , String.Empty)
```

The reason for this, is if the Select List and bound property share a name that often conflicts with inbound binding when the view renders.

Comment: DataBinding error - Genres model doesn't contain a property parentGenre, which doesn't make any sense to me because it should be looking in the Movies model.  The movieRepository.genres returns "get { return db.Genres; }

Comment: I made your update and it's the same error.  Is it because of what my repository is returning?  When I do m. intellisense picks up parentGenre.

Comment: OIC, Genres should be an id (int). you're using code first EF?

Comment: Yes, but why would Genres be an int?  I thought it had to be type Genres since it's a foreign key.

Comment: Code First is tuff. I played with it for fun but all my projects are db first. You're right that you need navigation, but you are only getting an id from the dropdown, not an entire object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27052/discussion-between-dave-a-and-andrew)

Comment: This is my first thing I have tried with code first.  I am still pretty new to this, but the projects I have worked on were db first too.  Do I need both Genres parentGenre and int genreId or just int GenreId?

Comment: enter the chat and i can explain better